# Is there any way to insert below nested json data into sql server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am working on a nested JSON data which I need to load into SQL SERVER 2012. The nested JSON contains two roots i.e. one column and another rows. I need to put value from row into the column. Please see the structure as below:

```
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "timestamp",
                    "type": "datetime"
                },
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "url",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "duration",
                    "type": "real"
                }
            ],
            "rows": [
                [
                    "2019-04-08T13:09:52.871Z",
                    "244",
                    "Internal",
                    "https://google.com",
                    1245,

                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result:**

```
timestamp    id    name    url    duration
2019-04-08    244    Internal    https://google.com    1245
```

Here , in sql server it should take column names from columns and value for each column from rows

Comment: This is a complex issue, but Phil Factor shared some solutions some time ago. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Yes Luis, its a little complex scenario where actually the values are not defined in a key value instead they are treated like array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that you store the json into a file named json.txt

```
import json

with open('json.txt') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    tableName = data['tables'][0]["name"]
    sqlCreateTable = 'CREATE TABLE ' + tableName + ' (\n'
    sqlInsertInto = 'INSERT INTO ' + tableName + ' ('
    for i in range(0,len(data['tables'][0]['columns'])):
        columnName = data['tables'][0]['columns'][i]['name']
        type = data['tables'][0]['columns'][i]['type']
        sqlCreateTable += columnName + " " + type + ',\n'
        sqlInsertInto += columnName + ', '

    sqlCreateTable = sqlCreateTable[:-2] + '\n);'
    sqlInsertInto = sqlInsertInto[:-2] + ')\nVALUES ('

    for value in data['tables'][0]['rows'][0]:
        sqlInsertInto += str(value) + ', '

    sqlInsertInto = sqlInsertInto[:-2] + ');'

    print(sqlCreateTable)
    print(sqlInsertInto)
```

Output for create table:

```
CREATE TABLE PrimaryResult (
timestamp datetime,
id string,
name string,
url string,
duration real
);
```

Output for insert into table:

```
INSERT INTO PrimaryResult (timestamp, id, name, url, duration)
VALUES (2019-04-08T13:09:52.871Z, 244, Internal, https://google.com, 1245);
```

Comment: Thanks Cristian Iacob for your solution. It actually took a little time to execute it but yes finally got the result using the above code in C#. Thanks alot for your help.